# Does MQTT inresponse can cause a reset due to network activity?

Tags: mqtt, arduino

**Setup description:**

1. I have 8 ESP8266s running an Arduino code to control windows shades up and down using relays, local switches and MQTT for remote operation, which work OK for the past few weeks.
2. MQTT broker is a PiZero, running in local network.
3. Subscription on a Linux machine show activity of all devices (boot, switching and MQTT messages ).

**Problem:**

1. 2 days ago, for the first time - ALL devices started to reboot one after the other, for several time, in time span of 5 minutes. Behavior does not seem as an AC power interference issue, since they are not connected to same line in main switch board, or any other power issue in other house devices ( light for example ).
2. my only guess at that time- was a Wifi issue, since they all share same network, perhaps even cyber thing :)
3. Yesterday, again same event, about same time at evening, 3 devices was resetting for few times.
4. I recalled that same time the other day I was uploading a file from my laptop to NAS ( in same wifi network as IoT devices and MQTT broker) during this events.
5. BTW MQTT broker did not undergo reset as IOT devices.

**Question:**

1. Is it possible that uploading a large file in local network, can interfere bandwidth wise, that can cause MQTT messages to fail reaching the broker ?
2. Can fail of MQTT send/receive  cause ESP8266 to reset ?

> EDIT1: adding CODE

some clarifications: command up/down can be initiated via a wall switch ( UP/ON/OFF ) or a MQTT command.
in case of network  malfunction or MQTT server error ( say something wrong with local RPI running broker ), manual operation should  be executed, so both wifi connection and MQTT connection have retries and timeouts to try while giving the user the ability to switch it as requested.

```c
//change deviceTopic !
//###################################################

#define deviceTopic "HomePi/Windows/Box_7"

// Service flags
bool useNetwork = true;
bool useWDT = true;
bool useSerial = false;
bool useOTA = true;
bool runPbit = true;

const char *ver = "ESP_WDT_OTA_2.2";

//###################################################

#define RelayOn LOW
#define SwitchOn LOW

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <TimeLib.h>
#include <NtpClientLib.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h> //MQTT
#include <Ticker.h> //WDT

// OTA libraries
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ArduinoOTA.h>
// #######################

// GPIO Pins for ESP8266
const int inputUpPin = 4;
const int inputDownPin = 5;
const int outputUpPin = 14;
const int outputDownPin = 12;
//##########################


//wifi creadentials
const char* ssid = "HomeNetwork";
const char* password = "1234";
//###################################


//MQTT broker parameters
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.2.200";
const char* user = "guy";
const char* passw = "1234";
// ######################################


// MQTT topics
const char* msgTopic = "HomePi/Messages";
const char* groupTopic = "HomePi/All";
const char* deviceName = deviceTopic;
const char* topicArry[] = {deviceTopic, groupTopic};
char stateTopic[50];
char availTopic[50];
// ##############################################

// MQTT connection flags
int mqttFailCounter = 0; // count tries to reconnect
long firstNotConnected = 0; // time stamp of first try
int connectionFlag = 0;
int MQTTretries = 5; // allowed tries to reconnect
// ######################


// GPIO status flags
bool outputUp_currentState;
bool outputDown_currentState;
bool inputUp_lastState;
bool inputDown_lastState;
bool inputUp_currentState;
bool inputDown_currentState;
// ###########################


// time interval parameters
const int clockUpdateInt = 1; // hrs to update clock
const int timeInt2Reset = 1500; // time between consq presses to init RESET cmd
const long MQTTtimeOut = (1000 * 60) * 5; //5 mins stop try to MQTT
const long WIFItimeOut = (1000 * 60) * 2; //2 mins try to connect WiFi
const long OTAtimeOut = (1000*60) * 1; // 1 minute to try OTA
long OTAcounter =0;
const int deBounceInt = 50; //
volatile int wdtResetCounter = 0;
const int wdtMaxRetries = 10; //seconds to bITE
// ############################


// RESET parameters
int manResetCounter = 0;  // reset press counter
int pressAmount2Reset = 3; // time to press button to init Reset
long lastResetPress = 0; // time stamp of last press
long resetTimer = 0;
// ####################


// assorted
char msg[150];
char timeStamp[50];
char bootTime[50];
bool firstRun = true;
// ###################


WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(espClient);
Ticker wdt;

void setup() {
        startGPIOs();
        if (useSerial) {
                Serial.begin(9600);
                Serial.println("SystemBoot");
                delay(10);
        }
        if (useNetwork) {
                startNetwork();
        }
        if(useOTA) {
                startOTA();
        }
        if (useWDT) {
                wdt.attach(1, feedTheDog); // Start WatchDog
        }
        if (runPbit) {
                PBit(); // PowerOn Bit
        }
}

void startGPIOs() {
        pinMode(inputUpPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
        pinMode(inputDownPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
        pinMode(outputUpPin, OUTPUT);
        pinMode(outputDownPin, OUTPUT);

        allOff();
}

void startNetwork() {
        long startWifiConnection = 0;
        if (useSerial) {
                Serial.println();
                Serial.print("Connecting to ");
                Serial.println(ssid);
        }

        startWifiConnection = millis();
        WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); //OTA Added
        WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
        // in case of reboot - timeOUT to wifi
        while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED && millis() - startWifiConnection < WIFItimeOut) {
                delay(500);
                if (useSerial) {
                        Serial.print(".");
                }
        }

        WiFi.setAutoReconnect(true);
        if (useSerial) {
                Serial.println("");
                Serial.println("WiFi connected");
                Serial.print("IP address: ");
                Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        }

        startMQTT();
        startNTP();
        get_timeStamp();
        strcpy(bootTime, timeStamp);
}

void startOTA() {
        char OTAname[100];
        int m = 0;
        // create OTAname from deviceTopic
        for (int i = ((String)deviceTopic).lastIndexOf("/") + 1; i < strlen(deviceTopic); i++) {
                OTAname[m] = deviceTopic[i];
                OTAname[m + 1] = '\0';
                m++;
        }

        OTAcounter = millis();

        // Port defaults to 8266
        ArduinoOTA.setPort(8266);

        // Hostname defaults to esp8266-[ChipID]
        ArduinoOTA.setHostname(OTAname);

        // No authentication by default
        // ArduinoOTA.setPassword("admin");

        // Password can be set with it's md5 value as well
        // MD5(admin) = 21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3
        // ArduinoOTA.setPasswordHash("21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3");

        ArduinoOTA.onStart([]() {
                String type;
                if (ArduinoOTA.getCommand() == U_FLASH) {
                        type = "sketch";
                } else { // U_SPIFFS
                        type = "filesystem";
                }

                // NOTE: if updating SPIFFS this would be the place to unmount SPIFFS using SPIFFS.end()
                if (useSerial) {
                        Serial.println("Start updating " + type);
                }
                // Serial.end();
        });
        if (useSerial) { // for debug
                ArduinoOTA.onEnd([]() {
                        Serial.println("\nEnd");
                });
                ArduinoOTA.onProgress([](unsigned int progress, unsigned int total) {
                        Serial.printf("Progress: %u%%\r", (progress / (total / 100)));
                });
                ArduinoOTA.onError([](ota_error_t error) {
                        Serial.printf("Error[%u]: ", error);
                        if (error == OTA_AUTH_ERROR) {
                                Serial.println("Auth Failed");
                        } else if (error == OTA_BEGIN_ERROR) {
                                Serial.println("Begin Failed");
                        } else if (error == OTA_CONNECT_ERROR) {
                                Serial.println("Connect Failed");
                        } else if (error == OTA_RECEIVE_ERROR) {
                                Serial.println("Receive Failed");
                        } else if (error == OTA_END_ERROR) {
                                Serial.println("End Failed");
                        }
                });
                // ArduinoOTA.begin();
                Serial.println("Ready");
                Serial.print("IP address: ");
                Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        }

        ArduinoOTA.begin();
}

void startMQTT() {
        createTopics(deviceTopic, stateTopic, availTopic);
        mqttClient.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
        mqttClient.setCallback(callback);
}

void startNTP() {
        NTP.begin("pool.ntp.org", 2, true);
        NTP.setInterval(1000 * 3600 * clockUpdateInt);
}

int connectMQTT() {
        // verify wifi connected
        if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
                if (useSerial) {
                        Serial.println("have wifi, entering MQTT connection");
                }
                while (!mqttClient.connected() && mqttFailCounter <= MQTTretries) {
                        if (useSerial) {
                                Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
                        }
                        // Attempt to connect
                        if (mqttClient.connect(deviceName, user, passw, availTopic, 0, true, "offline")) {
                                if (useSerial) {
                                        Serial.println("connected");
                                }
                                mqttClient.publish(availTopic, "online", true);
                                if (firstRun == true) {
                                        mqttClient.publish(stateTopic, "off", true);
                                        firstRun = false;
                                }
                                pub_msg("Connected to MQTT server");
                                for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(topicArry) / sizeof(char *); i++) {
                                        mqttClient.subscribe(topicArry[i]);
                                        sprintf(msg, "Subscribed to %s", topicArry[i]);
                                }
                                mqttFailCounter = 0;
                                return 1;
                        }
                        else {
                                if (useSerial) {
                                        Serial.print("failed, rc=");
                                        Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
                                        Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
                                }
                                delay(5000);
                                if (useSerial) {
                                        Serial.print("number of fails to reconnect MQTT");
                                        Serial.println(mqttFailCounter);
                                }
                                mqttFailCounter++;
                        }
                }
                if (useSerial) {
                        Serial.println("Exit without connecting MQTT");
                }
                mqttFailCounter = 0;
                return 0;
        }
        else {
                if (useSerial) {
                        Serial.println("Not connected to Wifi, abort try to connect MQTT broker");
                }
                return 0;
        }
}

void createTopics(const char *devTopic, char *state, char *avail) {
        sprintf(state, "%s/State", devTopic);
        sprintf(avail, "%s/Avail", devTopic);
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
        char incoming_msg[50];
        char state[5];
        char state2[5];
        char msg2[100];

        //      Display on Serial monitor only
        if (useSerial) {
                Serial.print("Message arrived [");
                Serial.print(topic);
                Serial.print("] ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (useSerial) {
                        Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
                }
                incoming_msg[i] = (char)payload[i];
        }
        incoming_msg[length] = 0;
        if (useSerial) {
                Serial.println("");
        }
        //      ##############################

        if (strcmp(incoming_msg, "status") == 0) {
                // relays state
                if (outputUp_currentState == RelayOn && outputDown_currentState == RelayOn) {
                        sprintf(state, "invalid Relay State");
                }
                else if (outputUp_currentState == !RelayOn && outputDown_currentState == RelayOn) {
                        sprintf(state, "DOWN");
                }
                else if (outputUp_currentState == RelayOn && outputDown_currentState == !RelayOn) {
                        sprintf(state, "UP");
                }
                else {
                        sprintf(state, "OFF");
                }

                // switch state
                if (inputUp_lastState == !RelayOn && inputDown_lastState == !RelayOn) {
                        sprintf(state2, "OFF");
                }
                else if (inputUp_lastState == RelayOn && inputDown_lastState == !RelayOn) {
                        sprintf(state2, "UP");
                }
                else if (inputUp_lastState == !RelayOn && inputDown_lastState == RelayOn) {
                        sprintf(state2, "DOWN");
                }
                sprintf(msg, "Status: Relay:[%s], Switch:[%s]", state, state2);
                pub_msg(msg);
        }
        else if (strcmp(incoming_msg, "up") == 0 || strcmp(incoming_msg, "down") == 0 || strcmp(incoming_msg, "off") == 0) {
                switchIt("MQTT", incoming_msg);
        }
        else if (strcmp(incoming_msg, "boot") == 0 ) {
                sprintf(msg, "Boot:[%s]", bootTime);
                pub_msg(msg);
        }
        else if (strcmp(incoming_msg, "ver") == 0 ) {
                sprintf(msg, "ver:[%s]", ver);
                pub_msg(msg);
        }
        else if (strcmp(incoming_msg, "pins") == 0 ) {
                sprintf(msg, "Switch: Up[%d] Down[%d], Relay: Up[%d] Down[%d]", inputUpPin, inputDownPin, outputUpPin, outputDownPin);
                pub_msg(msg);
        }
        else if (strcmp(incoming_msg, "ip") == 0 ) {
                char buf[16];
                sprintf(buf, "%d.%d.%d.%d", WiFi.localIP()[0], WiFi.localIP()[1], WiFi.localIP()[2], WiFi.localIP()[3] );
                sprintf(msg, "IP address:[%s]", buf);
                pub_msg(msg);
        }
        else if (strcmp(incoming_msg, "pbit") == 0 ) {
                pub_msg("PowerOnBit");
                PBit();
        }
        else if (strcmp(incoming_msg, "ota") == 0 ) {
                pub_msg("OTA allowed for 60 seconds");
                OTAcounter = millis();
        }
        else if (strcmp(incoming_msg, "reset") == 0 ) {
                sendReset("MQTT");
        }
}

void pub_msg(char *inmsg) {
        char tmpmsg[150];

        if (useNetwork == true) {
                get_timeStamp();
                sprintf(tmpmsg, "[%s] [%s]", timeStamp, deviceTopic );
                msgSplitter(inmsg, 95, tmpmsg, "#" );
        }
}

void msgSplitter( const char* msg_in, int max_msgSize, char *prefix, char *split_msg) {
        char tmp[120];

        if (strlen(prefix) + strlen(msg_in) > max_msgSize) {
                int max_chunk = max_msgSize - strlen(prefix) - strlen(split_msg);
                int num = ceil((float)strlen(msg_in) / max_chunk);
                int pre_len;

                for (int k = 0; k < num; k++) {
                        sprintf(tmp, "%s %s%d: ", prefix, split_msg, k);
                        pre_len = strlen(tmp);
                        for (int i = 0; i < max_chunk; i++) {
                                tmp[i + pre_len] = (char)msg_in[i + k * max_chunk];
                                tmp[i + 1 + pre_len] = '\0';
                        }
                        mqttClient.publish(msgTopic, tmp);
                }
        }
        else {
                sprintf(tmp, "%s %s", prefix, msg_in);
                mqttClient.publish(msgTopic, tmp);
        }
}

void get_timeStamp() {
        time_t t = now();
        sprintf(timeStamp, "%02d-%02d-%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", year(t), month(t), day(t), hour(t), minute(t), second(t));
}

void switchIt(char *type, char *dir) {
        char mqttmsg[50];
        bool states[2];
        // system states: up, down, off
        if (strcmp(dir, "up") == 0) {
                states[0] = RelayOn;
                states[1] = !RelayOn;
        }
        else if (strcmp(dir, "down") == 0) {
                states[0] = !RelayOn;
                states[1] = RelayOn;
        }
        else if (strcmp(dir, "off") == 0) {
                states[0] = !RelayOn;
                states[1] = !RelayOn;
        }

        // Case that both realys need to change state ( Up --> Down or Down --> Up )
        if (outputUp_currentState != states[0] && outputDown_currentState != states[1]) {
                allOff();

                delay(deBounceInt * 2);
                digitalWrite(outputUpPin, states[0]);
                digitalWrite(outputDownPin, states[1]);
        }
        // Case that one relay changes from/to off --> on
        else if (outputUp_currentState != states[0] || outputDown_currentState != states[1]) {
                digitalWrite(outputUpPin, states[0]);
                digitalWrite(outputDownPin, states[1]);
        }
        if (useNetwork == true) {
                mqttClient.publish(stateTopic, dir, true);
                sprintf(mqttmsg, "[%s] switched [%s]", type, dir);
                pub_msg(mqttmsg);
        }
        if(useSerial == true) {
                Serial.println(dir);
        }
}

void detectResetPresses() {
        if (millis() - lastResetPress < timeInt2Reset) {
                if (useSerial) {
                        Serial.print("Time between Press: ");
                        Serial.println(millis() - lastResetPress);
                }
                if (manResetCounter >= pressAmount2Reset) {
                        sendReset("Manual operation");
                        if (useSerial) {
                                Serial.println("Manual Reset initiated");
                        }
                        manResetCounter = 0;
                }
                else {
                        manResetCounter++;
                }
        }
        else {
                manResetCounter = 0;
        }
}

void sendReset(char *header) {
        char temp[150];

        if (useSerial) {
                Serial.println("Sending Reset command");
        }
        sprintf(temp, "[%s] - Reset sent", header);
        pub_msg(temp);
        delay(100);
        ESP.restart();
}

void PBit() {
        int pause = 2 * 5 * deBounceInt;
        allOff();
        delay(pause);
        digitalWrite(outputUpPin, RelayOn);
        delay(pause);
        digitalWrite(outputUpPin, !RelayOn);
        delay(pause);
        digitalWrite(outputDownPin, RelayOn);
        delay(pause);
        allOff();

}

void verifyMQTTConnection() {
        //  MQTT reconnection for first time or after first insuccess to reconnect
        if (!mqttClient.connected() && firstNotConnected == 0) {
                connectionFlag = connectMQTT();
                //  still not connected
                if (connectionFlag == 0 ) {
                        firstNotConnected = millis();
                }
                else {
                        mqttClient.loop();
                }
        }
        // retry after fail - resume only after timeout
        else if (!mqttClient.connected() && firstNotConnected != 0 && millis() - firstNotConnected > MQTTtimeOut) {
                //    after cooling out period - try again
                connectionFlag = connectMQTT();
                firstNotConnected = 0;
                if (useSerial) {
                        Serial.println("trying again to reconnect");
                }
        }
        else {
                mqttClient.loop();
        }
}

void allOff() {
        digitalWrite(outputUpPin, !RelayOn);
        digitalWrite(outputDownPin, !RelayOn);
        inputUp_lastState = digitalRead(inputUpPin);
        inputDown_lastState = digitalRead(inputDownPin);
}

void checkSwitch_PressedUp() {
        bool temp_inputUpPin = digitalRead(inputUpPin);

        if (temp_inputUpPin != inputUp_lastState) {
                delay(deBounceInt);
                if (digitalRead(inputUpPin) != inputUp_lastState) {
                        if (digitalRead(inputUpPin) == SwitchOn) {
                                switchIt("Button", "up");
                                inputUp_lastState = digitalRead(inputUpPin);

                                detectResetPresses();
                                lastResetPress = millis();
                        }
                        else if (digitalRead(inputUpPin) == !SwitchOn) {
                                switchIt("Button", "off");
                                inputUp_lastState = digitalRead(inputUpPin);
                        }
                }

                else { // for debug only
                        char tMsg [100];
                        sprintf(tMsg, "UP Bounce: cRead [%d] lRead[%d]", temp_inputUpPin, inputUp_lastState);
                        pub_msg(tMsg);
                }
        }

}

void checkSwitch_PressedDown() {
        bool temp_inputDownPin = digitalRead(inputDownPin);

        if (temp_inputDownPin != inputDown_lastState) {
                delay(deBounceInt);
                if (digitalRead(inputDownPin) != inputDown_lastState) {

                        if (digitalRead(inputDownPin) == SwitchOn) {
                                switchIt("Button", "down");
                                inputDown_lastState = digitalRead(inputDownPin);
                        }
                        else if (digitalRead(inputDownPin) == !SwitchOn) {
                                switchIt("Button", "off");
                                inputDown_lastState = digitalRead(inputDownPin);
                        }
                }
                else { // for debug only
                        char tMsg [100];
                        sprintf(tMsg, "Down Bounce: cRead[%d] lRead[%d]", temp_inputDownPin, inputDown_lastState);
                        pub_msg(tMsg);
                }
        }
}

void verifyNotHazardState() {
        if (outputUp_currentState == RelayOn && outputDown_currentState == RelayOn ) {
                switchIt("Button", "off");
                if (useSerial) {
                        Serial.println("Hazard state - both switches were ON");
                }
                sendReset("HazradState");
        }

}

void feedTheDog() {
        wdtResetCounter++;
        if (wdtResetCounter >= wdtMaxRetries) {
                sendReset("WatchDog");
        }
}

void acceptOTA() {
  if (millis() - OTAcounter <= OTAtimeOut) {
    ArduinoOTA.handle();
  }
}

void readGpioStates() {
        outputUp_currentState = digitalRead(outputUpPin);
        outputDown_currentState = digitalRead(outputDownPin);
        inputDown_currentState = digitalRead(inputDownPin);
        inputUp_currentState = digitalRead(inputUpPin);
}

void loop() {
        // read GPIOs
        readGpioStates();
        verifyNotHazardState(); // both up and down are ---> OFF

        // Service updates
        if (useNetwork) {
                verifyMQTTConnection();
        }
        if (useWDT) {
                wdtResetCounter = 0;
        }
        if (useOTA) {
                acceptOTA();
        }

        // react to commands (MQTT or local switch)
        checkSwitch_PressedUp();
        checkSwitch_PressedDown();

        delay(50);
}
```

Comment: @jsotola regrading 1: yes, as said, it happened twice when transferring large files. I'll post relevant part of code later on, but is it a known issue that traffic inside a network can cause MQTT fails to reach broker, will result an active reset ?

Comment: you are using a watchdog timer .... that is most likely the cause of the reset .... something is blocking the "feeding" of the watchdog ..... try increasing the timeout value

Comment: @jsotola here is my setup: few unit wdt was disabled, few others -time to bite changed to 2 sec. both group did not reset after 2 time of 8Gb file transfer as described